# Rolling indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I see a lot of topics on how to create rolling indices in Elasticsearch using logstash.

But is there a way to achieve the same i.e create indices on daily basis in elasticsearch without logstash?

I came a cross a post which says to run cron job to create the indices as date rolls, but that is a manual job I have to do, I was looking for out of the box options if available in elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) (which is what Logstash uses internally to achieve the creation of rolling indices)

Simply create a template with a name pattern like this and then everytime you index a document in an index whose name matches that pattern, ES will create the index for you:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/my_template -d '{
    "template" : "logstash-*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "my_type" : {
            "properties": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: I assume that this will only apply this template if an index is created but this will not create an index on the fly. What I mean is if "template" : "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}" then will this template create an index automatically whenever the date rolls or changes?

Comment: Yes, only if the new index doesn't exist (otherwise there's no reason to create a new one), which is exactly what you want.